# Change ::selection when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page that has a ::selection of a background color #FC5657; but when i click on a button i want that the ::selectioon changes to background color: white, and color black.

Is there a way to achive this. I am trying this but does not work, please help.

```
$('.circle').click(function(){
        $('::selection').css('background','white');
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you currently have?

Comment: there it is i want to change the ::selection

Answer (score 1):

You can make it with class adding to the block who own selected text. It can be

or `<body>` even `<HTML>` element.

All you need is class toggling function on button and CSS-style for that class.

**CSS**

```
.classYouNeed ::selection {
    background: red;
}

::selection {
    background: green;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.someButton').on('click', function(){
        $('body').toggleClass('classYouNeed');
    });
});
```

Comment: How to change the css class on jquery?

Comment: $('body').addClass('newSelectionClass') or you can $().toggleClass()

Comment: What i don´t understand is how to write on css the ('newSelectionClass'), that your talking about

Comment: ::-moz-selection { background: #FC5657;color: white;}
    ::selection { background: #FC5657;color: white;} currently i have this on my css